# Returning one cell from Codeigniter Query

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I want to query a table and only need one cell returned. Right now the only way I can think to do it is:

```
 $query = $this->db->query('SELECT id FROM crops WHERE name = "wheat"');
 if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
     $row = $query->row();
     $crop_id = $row->id;
 }
```

What I want is, since I'm select 'id' anyway, for that to be the result. IE: $query = 'cropId'.

Any ideas? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible. Just use `AND` in your query:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT id FROM crops WHERE name = "wheat" AND id = {$cropId}');
```

Or you could use the raw power of the provided [Active Record](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select) class:

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->from('crops');
$this->db->where('name','wheat');
$this->db->where('id',$cropId);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

If you just want the `cropId` from the whole column:

```
foreach ($query->result()->id as $cropId)
{
    echo $cropId;
}
```

Try this out, I'm not sure if it will work:

```
$cropId = $query->first_row()->id;
```

Comment: I'm trying to select the cropId from the crops table.

Comment: @DylanButh, you want to select an id where id is equal to id from crop table also? where is your id coming from a form?

Comment: So you only need one `column` returned, not just a single cell?

Comment: I just want the cropId based on the name. I provide the name of the crop and need to know what Id is associated with that.

Comment: Ok. Fixed. That `foreach` example should do it

Comment: It will only return one row though so i would prefer not to use a foreach if I dont have to. Waste of time/space.

Comment: Last ditch effort, check the last edit. If this doesn't work, I'm sunk.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you want to swap your quotes around: use " for your PHP strings, and ' for your SQL strings. First of all, it would not be compatible with PostgreSQL and other database systems that check such things.

Otherwise, as Christopher told you, you can test the crop identifier in your query. Only if you define a string between '...' in PHP, the variables are not going to be replaced in the strings. So he showed the wrong PHP code.

```
"SELECT ... $somevar ..."
```

will work better.

Yet, there is a security issue in writing such strings: it is very dangerous because $somevar could represent some additional SQL and completely transform your SELECT in something that you do not even want to think about. Therefore, the Active Record as mentioned by Christopher is a lot safer.

Comment: [O rly?](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

Comment: Looks like it on that page you linked here... doesn't it? 8-)