# Get the value of a cell in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter to write a few lines of simple code to get value from the mysql table.

What I've tried:

```
$interview_id=45
$category_raw = $this->db->query("select category from interview where interview_id='$interview_id'");
$category = $category_raw->first_row();
```

But for some reason, the $category is shown as "array()", while I actually want to get the value within.

Any advice on how to proceed?

Thanks so much,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning one cell from Codeigniter Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271352/returning-one-cell-from-codeigniter-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can take the value like

```
   $category = $category_raw->first_row()->category;
```

because `first_row()` alwise return value as object

[documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$interview_id=45;
$category_raw = $this->db->query("select category from interview where interview_id=$interview_id");
$category = $category_raw->first_row()->category;
```

Or with active record

```
$interview_id=45;
$this->db->select("category");
$this->db->where("interview_id",$interview_id);
$category_raw = $this->db->get("interview");
$category = $category_raw->first_row()->category;
```